# Nonlinear Gompertz model

Tags: regression, model, nonlinear

Is it possible to use Gompertz to model a non time series data? i.e. change t (time) into x (independent variables). Data does not involve growth or survival.

Comment: Some more information might help to obtain better answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can fit any model to any data. The question is whether the values of the parameters will be useful or meaningful. If the independent variable is not time, it is hard to imagine how to interpret the parameters of the [Gompertz model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gompertz_function).